How to pop a widget when the argument becomes null in a stateful widget?
Let's say the ManageBookingPage widget requires an object called trip as an argument. But this widget has the ability to modify the received argument such that it becomes null (trip = null).
I want this widget to pop out of the tree automatically when trip becomes null. What would be the best approach in achieving this?
class ManageBookingPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ManageBookingPage({
    super.key,
    required this.trip,
  });

  final BusTrip trip;

  @override
  State<ManageBookingPage> createState() => _ManageBookingPageState();
}

class _ManageBookingPageState extends State<ManageBookingPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      child: Text(widget.trip.date.toString()),
    );
}


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Solution
The solution I settled on:

Make the parameter trip nullable.
Add a null check in a conditional statement inside the build method and pop the widget out of tree if the argument becomes null.


class ManageBookingPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ManageBookingPage({
    super.key,
    required this.trip,
  });

  final BusTrip? trip;

  @override
  State<ManageBookingPage> createState() => _ManageBookingPageState();
}

class _ManageBookingPageState extends State<ManageBookingPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    BusTrip? widgetTrip = widget.trip;

    if (widgetTrip != null) {
      String date = widget.trip.date.toString(); 
      return SizedBox(
       child: Text(date),
      );
    } else {
      return Builder(
        builder: (context) {
          Navigator.pop(context);
          return const SizedBox();
        },
      );
    }
  }
}


You can use the ternary operator to achieve it.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ManageBookingPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ManageBookingPage({
    super.key,
    required this.trip,
  });

  final BusTrip? trip;

  @override
  State<ManageBookingPage> createState() => _ManageBookingPageState();
}

class _ManageBookingPageState extends State<ManageBookingPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return widget.trip != null ? SizedBox(
        child: Text(widget.trip.date.toString()),
      ) : const SizedBox.shrink();
  }
}

In this case if trip is not null it will render the widget :
SizedBox(
   child: Text(widget.trip.date.toString()),
)

And if the trip is null it will display SizedBox.shrink(), and the previous widget won't be rendered, removing it out of the tree.

Offstage simply hides its children. I want to pop the widget from the widget tree when the trip becomes null.

@FarajShaikh Okay, so I think using ternary operators would achieve it. I have added the code example in my answer.

I tried to add trip management in this page and add a listener when the trip value has been change to null the page will be poped.
class ManageBookingPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ManageBookingPage({
    super.key,
    required this.trip,
  });

  final BusTrip trip;

  @override
  State<ManageBookingPage> createState() => _ManageBookingPageState();
}

class _ManageBookingPageState extends State<ManageBookingPage> {
  // Define new trip variable for this page for managing trip value state
  late final ValueNotifier<BusTrip?> trip;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // Assign trip for this page from previous page (parameter argument)
    trip = ValueNotifier<BusTrip?>(widget.trip);

    // Add [trip] listener to notify when trip value has been changed
    //
    // The function inside listener will be executed when the [trip.value] changed.
    trip.addListener(() {
      if (trip.value == null) Navigator.pop(context);
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    trip.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Text(widget.trip.date.toString()),

          // Add distance for other widget
          const SizedBox(height: 16),

          // A button for remove trip value
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              // Remove trip value by assign it to null
              trip.value = null;
            },
            child: const Text('Remove Trip'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


To automatically remove the ManageBookingPage widget from the navigation stack when the trip becomes null, you can use a ValueNotifier and listen for changes to trip. When trip becomes null, you can use Navigator.pop() to remove the widget from the stack.
Example code:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ManageBookingPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ManageBookingPage({
    super.key,
    required this.tripNotifier,
  });

  final ValueNotifier<BusTrip?> tripNotifier;

  @override
  State<ManageBookingPage> createState() => _ManageBookingPageState();
}

class _ManageBookingPageState extends State<ManageBookingPage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Add a listener to the ValueNotifier
    widget.tripNotifier.addListener(_checkTrip);
  }

  void _checkTrip() {
    // Check if the trip is null
    if (widget.tripNotifier.value == null) {
      Navigator.of(context).pop(); // Remove the widget from the navigation stack
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Remove the listener when the widget is disposed
    widget.tripNotifier.removeListener(_checkTrip);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      child: Text(widget.tripNotifier.value?.date.toString() ?? 'No trip'),
    );
  }
}

class BusTrip {
  final DateTime date;
  BusTrip(this.date);
}

Explanation

ValueNotifier<BusTrip?> tripNotifier: A ValueNotifier is used to observe changes in trip.

addListener(_checkTrip): Adds a listener to tripNotifier that triggers _checkTrip whenever trip changes.

_checkTrip: Checks if trip is null. If so, it calls Navigator.of(context).pop() to remove the widget from the navigation stack.

dispose(): Removes the listener when the widget is disposed to prevent memory leaks.


